# ASP.NET - Change Stylesheet Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I need to save changes on my Stylesheet dynamically, for example, i have my styles.css with:

```
#body {
    color: grey;
}
```

My default.aspx:

```
<body id="body" runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="but" runat="server" onclick="but_Click"/>
```

My C# code:

```
protected void but_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            body.Attributes["bgcolor"] = "lightblue";
        }
```

Is it possible to permanently save the changes i have made on my CSS file?

Thank you all!
Firmino

Comment: if you need to changes on  Style-sheet dynamically then you need file handling to change the style-sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you can't!!

Because CSS is server file and we can't update it directly, but you can directly add style to control.

I am not sure about this but you can try some dirty tricks i.e. by simple Read and Write of file and Appending style at bottom of CSS file.

Give it a try and see if it works or not?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816149

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I guess that's what i really have to do to solve this issue :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx for more information.

This does not change your stylesheet permanently, if you need that, I'd go with the other answer provided above :).

Comment: Thanks for your reply RvdV79. That's not the ideal solution but thanks anyway!

Comment: I agree, because you want to change the stylesheet permanently (right?). However, you could try to build up your stylesheet dynamically from stored entries in let's say a database. However, that is still quite some work to perform.

Comment: Thanks again mate. That's one of my ideas to perform this task but i was trying not to overload the database with this. And it is indeed some work to perform :) Thanks!